# On each draw, you bet half of your present fortune that you will draw a white ball What is your expected final fortune?

Tags: probability-theory

You have 80 dollars and play the following game. An urn contains two white
 balls and two black balls. You draw the balls out one at a time without
 replacement until all the balls are gone. On each draw, you bet half of your
 present fortune that you will draw a white ball. What is your expected final
 fortune?

For this one, I thought about summing up 40 (1/2) -40 (1/2) to get 0, then I knew if I took one of the urns out, there could be a 1/3 or 2/3 chance of getting a white ball, so, I added 40(1/3)-40 (1/3) to get 0. Also, I did the same procedure again with the 2/3. But all I kept getting was zero. How do u find the correct expected value?

Comment: If you are sure to draw all the four balls, then you have to win twice and lose twice. It is actually unclear what you win if the ball is white.

Comment: Did you try to compute your final fortune for some definite sequences of white/black balls? If you do that, you are in for a surprise, which could suggest you 1. the result, and 2. how to prove it...

Answer (score 4):

Your final fortune will always be the same number, since you guess white every time. On two of the draws your fortune will be multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$ and on the other two it will be by $\frac{3}{2}$, since you will be wrong exactly twice and right exactly twice. Thus your final fortune is
$$80*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{3}{2}*\frac{3}{2}$$
$$80*\frac{9}{16}$$
$$45$$

Answer (score 0):

I would say build a tree.

The balls may come out WWBB, WBWB, WBBW, etc.  There are only 16 cases to go through.  Each is equally likely.

Now, hopefully you after the 3rd case one you realize that something is up.

Next question, is there an ideal betting strategy that maximizes your expected result?  Turns out that there is.